# Platform independent method of getting IP address of primary network interface

Tags: ruby, ip

I was wondering if there was a way to get the primary network interface's (in my case, `wlan0`) IP address, regardless of platform, in Ruby.

In Python3, I had the following function:

```
def getIPAddress():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    return s.getsockname()[0]
```

Which I could call with:

```
print("My IP address: " + getIPAddress())
```

Which would work on Windows, Linux and Mac.

I am sure there is a way of doing this in Ruby, but I haven't found anything yet.

So I was wondering if you knew any way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the "primary network interface"? If you can explain what the "primary network interface" is, then you can probably also write a program to find its IP address(es). Note that in most modern OSs, any network interface has about half a dozen addresses, and may have many more. (On my work laptop, the Gigabit Ethernet interface has ~15 addresses and I constantly add and remove some depending on the project I am working on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for Ruby's [Socket](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#class-Socket-label-Quick+start) class, your Python code can be translated almost 1:1 to Ruby:

```rb
require "socket"

def get_ip_address
  s = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM)
  s.connect(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(80, "8.8.8.8"))
  Socket.unpack_sockaddr_in(s.getsockname)[1]
end

puts "My IP address: #{get_ip_address}"
```